# format array quantities and update them

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a state with pinia which is an arrangement with two quantities. I have a component where I use vueform slider and I have two inputs where I show the maximum and minimum amount of the slider using v-model. In the slider I pass the minimum and maximum amounts that are the same as the array and using v-model I change them, in each button I have an input event where I call a function where the value of the input is going to move the slider either manually or maximum. It shows me the value of the slider fine on each input. But how can I format these amounts so that I add the commas in larger amounts and add the dollar sign ($)?

Slider

```
<Slider
   class="slider"
   v-model="sliderStore.priceRange"
   :lazy="false"
   :min="0"
   :max="5000000"
   :format="priceFormat"
   :tooltips="true"
/>
```

pinia state

```
priceRange: [ 0, 5000000],
```

inputs

```
<input 
       type="text"
       class="text-center" 
       v-model="sliderStore.priceRange[0]"
       @input="event => sliderStore.handlePriceValue(event.target.value)"
        > 
                              
  <input 
     type="text" 
     class="text-center" 
     v-model="sliderStore.priceRange[1]"
     @input="event => sliderStore.handlePriceValue2(event.target.value)"
   >
```

functions that change the value of the input and modify the slider

```
handlePriceValue(value1){
      this.priceRange[0] = value1;
    },
handlePriceValue2(value2){
      this.priceRange[1] = value2;
    },
```

Comment: What is the `Slider` component, do you use a library or a custom component?

Comment: use the library vueform/slider

Comment: Could you provide `priceFormat` function?

Comment: yes, return {priceFormat: { suffix: '$', decimals: 2}}, only this is to show it in the tooltips, which will be hidden, I just want to format the amounts in the inputs

Answer (score 1):

`vueform/slider` has a `format` function which enables to you to `format` the tooltip number, Also you can use `toLocaleString('en-US')`, to formate the large numbers.

html

```
<Slider
   class="slider"
   v-model="sliderStore.priceRange"
   :lazy="false"
   :min="0"
   :max="5000000"
   :format="priceFormat"
   :tooltips="true"
/>
```

js

```
<script>
import Slider from '@vueform/slider'

  export default {
    components: { Slider },
    data: () => ({
      priceFormat: function (value) {
        return `${value.toLocaleString('en-US')}$`
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

For formatting `inputs`, you need to add `keyup` event listener and update the value of the input with formatting.

```
<input 
   type="text"
   class="text-center" 
   v-model="sliderStore.priceRange[0]"
   @keyup="event => sliderStore.handlePriceValue(event.target.value)"
> 
                          
  <input 
     type="text" 
     class="text-center" 
     v-model="sliderStore.priceRange[1]"
     @keyup="event => sliderStore.handlePriceValue2(event.target.value)"
   >

handlePriceValue(value){
   var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
   this.priceRange[0]  = n.toLocaleString('en-US');
},
handlePriceValue2(value){
      var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
      this.priceRange[1] = n.toLocaleString('en-US');
},
```

Comment: it works in the tooltip but in the inputs it keeps showing me the amount without formatting

Comment: I update the answer to handle `inputs` formatting too.

Comment: It still shows the same, I guess I have to change the amount in the priceRange array, which is what is shown in the inputs

Comment: Yes, I already do that in the code, with `this.priceRange[0]  = n.toLocaleString('en-US');` and `this.priceRange[1] = n.toLocaleString('en-US');`

Comment: It doesn't change the amount of the input, it continues to show the same, when using `sliderStore.priceRange[0].toLocaleString('eu')`, outside the input, it does it well, it does what I'm looking for, when adding it in the v-model to show it in the input it marks an error